# "Sorry this app is not supported on this server" when adding workflow to SharePoint app

Tags: workflow, error, app

I am facing the following issue while deploying a SharePoint hosted app.

1. When I add 2013 workflow to app and deploy app in app catalog, I cannot install the app. This message comes up:

   > Sorry, this app is not supported on your server.
2. When I remove the workflow from the app, the app installs properly.

My environment details:

- Workflow manager 1.0 is installed on a farm
- App environment is setup properly.
- SharePoint 2013 is installed on all farms.
- Using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate to create workflow apps

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to update your Workflow Manager 1.0 with CU2.

Will resolve your problem, no need to change ID.  (This CU2 update worked for me.)

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the capability ID in appmanifest.xml which is generated by Visual Studio 2013 under this section:

```
<AppPrerequisites> 
<AppPrerequisite Type="Capability" ID="CDD8F991-B459-4512-8048-03D5A03FF27E" />
```

Right ID is **B1DDD88F-6ADD-4700-B5CD-18E451635E24**

More details can be seen here : [Capability ID issue while publishing app with workflow](http://www.sharepoint-reference.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=39)

Comment: I have changed my AppPrerequisite ID. I can now add that app, but I cant see my workflow which I have added.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the answer provided here. In my scenario this post helps. http://sharepoint-360.blogspot.in

Comment: Please add substantial part of the post in your answer, link-only answers tend to get void if the link is broken.